# Qué es Body-parse y para qué sirve

Tags: nodejs, express, npm

Estoy aprendiendo Nodejs y hay un paquete llamado "body-parser" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) que recomendó un profesor.
El punto es que he visto otro paquete en la web de npmjs.com llamado "body-parse" (así tal cual, sin la "r" al final: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parse) y quería saber si alguien lo ha usado antes y si saben para qué sirve. En la página de body-parse no aparece una descripción de para qué sirve pero muestran que tiene más de 2000 descargas por semana.
Saludos

Comment: Es un paquete vacio. Las descargas deben ser de la gente que comete un error tipografico al intentar instalar "body-parser".

Comment: Body-parse no sirve para nada y body-parser te permite tener acceso al objeto req.body cuando haces una peticion post.

Comment: Si estás usando Express [versión 4.16.4](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/5.0/History.md#4164--2018-10-10) o superior, no hace falta `body-parser` para nada, ya que viene incorporado por defecto en Express como una dependencia, con las funciones `express.json()` y `express.urlencoded()`. Desconozco el curso que estás haciendo, pero si te recomiendan usar `body-parser` junto con Express, tal vez no esté muy actualizado. Saludos